# Falha HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http-request

Estou tentando consumir um WebService via WebRequest no c# e simplesmente não consigo nenhuma resposta do servidor. Porém, via Postman eu consigo a resposta utilizando os mesmos parâmetros.

código:

```
            var JsonCliente = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clienteMP);
            var payload = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonCliente);

            String username = APIKey;
            String password = "";
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

            string URLRequest = URI;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLRequest);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

                settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clienteMP, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, settings);
                writer.Write(data);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                return myObject.ToString();
            }
```

a exception é dada na linha `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();` , a mensagem de erro é:

InnerException = {"Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto"}

Message = "Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto."

Comment: Encontrei um POST falando sobre isso no forum do MSDN (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/41d9f2f6-e163-4f6d-b226-c8ce925e1c51/erro-em-retorno-de-webservice?forum=webgeralpt), tente fazer isso: protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);

            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            webRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10;
            return webRequest;
        }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Encontrei a solução no link do comentário, o problema era protocolo de segurança, bastou adicionar a seguinte linha antes de ser feito o resquest:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Que bom que deu certo :)

Comment: Cara! Eu tava a 3 dias procurando uma solulção ! A sua funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: Perfeito, não sabia disso.